# Where should my duplicate check be for Azure Table Storage models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I have an Azure table datastore and here's my model for one class:

```
 public class Product : TableServiceEntity
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Title required")]
        [DisplayName("Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

There is more to this but the most important thing is PartitionKey, RowKey (hidden here) and Title.

What I want to do is to ensure that no record is saved that has the same title as another. I currently use a service layer for everything to do with the model.

Should my check there's no record already with the same title be part of this service layer or should it somehow be in the model itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure storage can only enforce uniqueness based upon partition key and row key. Any other uniqueness needs to be enforced by your own logic.

Comment: Yeah but should I put the logic inside of the "set" or in the service layer?

Comment: If your Model is not aware of the Context and only has object properties, than the check for uniqueness has to be "outside" during persistence.  I hesitate to mention layers, because I'm not familiar with your architecture

Answer (score 1):

You can't have that check in the model. You shall do it in the service layer, and raise appropriate exception if entity being saved duplicates a Title.

Az Igorek mentioned, the only unique constraint in Azure Table Storage is **partition key + row key**.